# display a text only in one language in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, hide, display, wpml

I have a Bilingual Wordpress website that uses WPML (french & english). On top of my page simple.php, I have a code that send an email with the blog post title as the subject, everything works fine except that when i switch to english (or back to french), it is still written in both french and english (obviously).

Right now my code looks like this

...

```
    <div class="l-content">

        <?php do_action( 'us_before_single' ) ?>
            <section class="l-section">
                /* french */
                <div class="l-section-h i-cf" style="padding-bottom:0 !important; text-align:right;">
                <a href="mailto:contact@contact.com?subject=Demande d'information pour la formation <?php wp_title() ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Plus d'informations &gt;</a>
                </div>

                /* english */
                <div class="l-section-h i-cf" style="padding-bottom:0 !important; text-align:right;">
                <a href="mailto:contact@contact.com?subject=More info request <?php wp_title() ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Get more info &gt;</a>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?php

        while ( have_posts() ){
            the_post();

            us_load_template( 'templates/blog/single-post', $template_vars );
        }
        ?>

        <?php do_action( 'us_after_single' ) ?>

    </div>
```

...

My question is how can I make it detect the language and only display the right language, or hide the other language?

Comment: You can check for `_icl_current_language` cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPML Constant ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE to get the current language, and apply an if condition to print only the wanted div